Wrong values with Sigmoid function on Tiffiles and multi-classes - I don't generate a 3 channel output file?
I have 3 target masks (each 1 channel tifs) with values between 0 and 1. My goal is to achive an output layer with 3 channels (each is a mask) to use this later for machine learning segmentation in images.
I got the 3 mask layer by using the Polygon to Raster Tool in ArcGIS. There I defined the Value of 1 for each layer.
My function is:
def mask(mask_paths, output):

    ## Import 3 masks
    ## Import as float to avoid boolean error
    masks = [tifffile.imread(path).astype(float) for path in mask_paths]

    ## Combine masks into a single mask with 3 channels
    mask_comb = np.stack(masks, axis=-1)

    ## Apply sigmoid function to each channel to get values between 0 and 1
    # for each channel
    mask_comb = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-mask_comb))

    ## Determine the category of each pixel to get maximum value
    mask_cat = np.argmax(mask_comb, axis=-1)

    tifffile.imwrite(output, mask_cat.astype(np.uint8))

I used .astype(float) because I got the error
TypeError: The numpy boolean negative, the -operator, is not supported, use the~ operator or the logical_not function instead.
I also generate output. But after checking with QGIS I see that I only get a Single-Channel tif (Gray-Scale) with a value of 0 to 2. What step did I miss here and why my sigmoid function apperently doesn't work (because of the stange channel value between 0 and 2)?
Maybe I just also doesn't get the logic. I am new in python, thank you a lot :)
